# nitroflare.comにおけるログイン認証のあるページへ curl でアクセスする方法について

Tags: linux, cookie, curl

下記のアップロードサイト(NitroFlare)へのアクセスをLinuxのコマンドラインで実現しようと、
curlでログインしようとしてもうまくできません。（ログインエラーページが返る）
https://nitroflare.com/login

ちなみに他のアップロードサイト（rapidgator）では同じ手法で実現できたのですが、
このサイトでは何か特殊な手順が必要なのでしょうか。
もしくは、何かの考慮もれでしょうか。この辺の技術に詳しい方おられましたら、
ご教授頂けると嬉しいです。

実施した手順は以下の通りです。

```
curl -sS -c cookie.txt https://nitroflare.com/login \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    --data-urlencode "email=xxx" \
    --data-urlencode "password=xxx" \
    --data-urlencode "login=" \
    --data-urlencode "token=xxx"
```

※パラメータは、GUIでchromeでアクセスした際の内容を確認し、
　email/passowrdは正規に登録したもの（GUIからのアクセス正常ログインできる）で、
　loginは未指定、tokenは初回アクセス時に取得したものを設定しています。
※ `--data-urlencode` で指定せず、
　`-d "email=xxx&password=xxx&login=&token=xxx"`
　といった感じの１パラメータで指定しても同じでした。
（通信内容をキャプチャしてみる限りは、GUIでアクセスした際と同じようなパラメータを送信しているように見えます。）

以上、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: この記事 [Trying to add a new module Nitroflare #20](https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare-modules-legacy/issues/20) でdownloadは出来ていないようですが、後ろにloginのスクリプトが記載されているので、参考になるかもしれません。他に今も使えるかは不明ですが [plowshare-modules-legacy/nitroflare.sh](https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare-modules-legacy/blob/master/nitroflare.sh) で`anonymous`でのdownloadと情報取得が出来るようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。リンク先の内容を確認してみました。が、コードが全量なくpost_login以降が追えず分からずじまいでした。他の方も苦労しているようですね。plowshare で anonymouse の方法も確認しましたが、今回は Login認証を行ってできる方法を確立したいです。引き続き、どなたかわかる方居られましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: curl に渡す request header に `User-Agent` を追加してみてはどうでしょうか。例えば `-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...'` など

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。user-agentもGUIのブラウザアクセスし成功する際と同じ値（ Mozilla/5.0…）を設定して試してみましたがダメでした。難しいです。。

Comment: スクリプトよけで、javascript呼び出しのphpで、Cookieをセットしてしている様です。（挙動不審なloginはreCAPTCHAのページへ リダイレクトされます。）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確かにGUIブラウザで通信ログを確認してみると、クッキーを付与してアクセスしてました。ちなみに、全く同じ値で別の装置からコマンドラインでcurlアクセスしても正常に結果が返らないということは、端末に依存した何か情報を含むcookieを渡しているのでしょうか。。記載の「スクリプトよけで、javascript…」というところが、自分の知識では明るくないので正しく理解できないのですが、どうにか回避する手立てはないのでしょうか。ひとまず、ありがとうございました。